# only one external monitor gets video signal, even though two external monitors get detected

Tags: nvidia, usb, 22.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a three display setup, 1st screen is the laptop screen, second screen is my monitor connected to physical HDMI port on my laptop, and 3rd monitor connected to usb-c port (via usb-c docking station, that has 2 HDMI outputs) which also has display-port within it.

Only one external monitor gets input. If I disconnect the HDMI cable for 2nd monitor, the 3rd monitor gets video signal. If I connect the HDMI cable back for 2nd monitor, 2nd monitor gets signal and 3rd monitor screen goes black. If I connect both monitors to the HDMI outs in my usb-c docking station, they both go black.

In ubuntu settings>Displays, all three monitors are detected. In nvidia settings app, both external monitors are shown.

On switching to windows, everything works fine.

Machine Details:

- Laptop: MSI Bravo 17 C7VEK (ryzen 7735 CPU)
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- Graphics card + driver: RTX 4060 + 545 driver (proprietary)

I did `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and it shows `x11`

```
❯ uname -a
```

> Linux sun 6.2.0-37-generic #38~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu
> Nov  2 18:01:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any help is appreciated.